# Can I create a link in a digium email template to add a phone number to my call block list?

Tags: api, asterisk

I work in an office which uses Digium Swtichvox. We recently moved offices and had to get new phone numbers. Many of these numbers are frequently being called by debt collectors or other wrong number calls.

When we let a call go to voicemail, we get an email. I would like to edit this email template to include a link to provide a one-click mechanism to add a number to my blocked call lists.

I see that Digium exposes an API, but I don't see a way to construct a URL to make a link to add a number to my block list. Is this possible? If so what API calls or URL pattern do I need to use?

I have a direct link to get to the "call block" page, `https://phone.mycompanyinteranet.com/main?cmd=call_options#pageTab=block`. Unfortunately it uses a form with randomly generated ids for the attribute field. So I can't do something simple like constructing a URL and putting that in the template.